# How to add box shaders to plot Highcharts

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts

I have a Highcharts plot which looks something like this

[image]

representing time series data for several different series. The thing is, sometimes the data for a particular series is "unavailable" (as you can see with the purple series above), and so the data values are NaN.

I want to have some way of "capping" each series wherever there are NaN values - my ideas was to use [plotBands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands) for the corresponding color of each series between all NaN values. However, I cannot seem to figure out if this is even possible. I have done plenty of research and found demos which treat "area with missing points" by simply not displaying anything (as my current chart does), such as [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-missing/gray) with this image:

[image]

but I'm imagining a treatment of NaN values that looks something like this instead (I apologize for my lack of artistry)

[image]

**Is this possible with Highcharts?**

Comment: what you want in that blue scribbled portion . It will be clear or it will be full blue color

Comment: @Deep3015 Full blue color!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use load events in chat to add plot band

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwh2x9c2/)

```
   chart: {
    type: 'area',
    spacingBottom: 30,
    events: {
             load: function () {
             var series_data=this.series[1].data;//this is second series data
             for(var i=0;i<series_data.length;i++){
                  if(series_data[i].y==null){
                     //adds plot band
                      this.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({  
                          from: i-1, //point back
                          to: i+1,   //point after
                          color: '#0066ff',
                      });
                  }
             }

        }
    }

},
```